# JavaScript - How to access a specific value in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've this array of objects:

```
    var buArray = [{'31': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC'}},
                   {'33': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC'}},
                   {'51': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC', '3':'SR', '5':'WIN'}},
                   {'52': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC', '3':'SR', '4':'JU'}},
                   {'53': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC', '3':'SR', '5':'WIN'}},
                   {'54': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC', '3':'SR', '5':'WIN'}},
                   {'55': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC', '3':'SR', '6':'PP'}}]
```

How can I access for example to this specific object(with id 31) for example: "{'31': {'1':'VN', '2':'AC'}}" ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find matching elements in the array:

```
function findEntry(a, key) {
    return a.filter(function(e) {
        var k = Object.keys(e);
        return k.length === 1 && k[0] === key;
    });
}
```

The result will still be an array, but it'll only contain elements matching the predicate.

If it's possible that the inner object might contain multiple keys then replace the `return` line with:

```
return k.indexOf('31') >= 0;
```

NB: `Object.keys`, `.filter` and `.indexOf` are ES5 functions.  Shims are readily available for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In standard javascript you have to loop over each item and check the keys.

```
function find_object_with_key(arr, key) {
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {   // For each index in the array
        var item = arr[i];                // Retrieve the item
        for(k in item) {                  // For each key in the object
            if(!item.hasOwnProperty(k)) { // Check if the item is a proper member of the object
                continue;
            }
            if(k == key) {                // Check if the key matches what we are searching for
                return item;              // Return the item
            }
        }
    }
    return false;                         // In case of failure return false
}
```

Comment: do NOT use `for ... in` on arrays!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using underscore.js, you could use the `_.where(list, properties)` function which it has rather than re-inventing the mechanism. You can read about it here: http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 0):

That's a very confusing data structure. At the moment none of your objects has an `id` property, so you can't do a lookup on that - the way it is written you have objects with *properties* of 31, 33, 51 etc. You'd have to write a custom function to search for any object.

If you can I'd suggest reworking each object in the array to be something like

```
{
    id: 31,
    data: {
        '1':'VN',
        '2':'AC'
    }
}
```

But if not, with the data as written, a function like the following (uses simple iteration, there are more efficient ways)

```
function findObj(objID, array){
    var i, j, len1, len2;
    for(i = 0, len1 = array.length; i < len1; i++){
        var keys = Object.keys(array[i]);
        for(j = 0, len2 = keys.length; j < len2; j++){
            if(keys[j] === objID) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    // object hasn't been found
    return null;
}
```

and call it thus

```
findObj("31", buArray);
```